# Am I Jewish By All Accounts?

Tags: halacha

I have been a religious college student for the past two years. I was raised Jewish, underwent a Brit Milah at my birth, was a Bar Mitzvah, and my father's side of the family is Jewish, ethnically and religiously. My mother converted prior to her marriage to my father. She underwent a Mikvah, Bet Din, and acquired significant knowledge about Judaism. She began her conversion process at a Conservative Synagogue, but my dad and my mom moved to a different state after a certain period of time. Thus, she finished her conversion at a Reform Synagogue, in Tennessee. All of the Conservative rabbis that I know contend that my mother's conversion was kosher and I am 100% Jewish. However, I have received mostly mixed answers regarding whether I am Jewish by Orthodox accounts, creating a bit of uncertainty. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Hello Alex, welcome to Mi Yodeya. In general, Orthodox doesn't accept non-Orthodox conversions. However, it's best if you ask a real Orthodox rabbi directly, to explain your entire story and see what he says. Mi Yodeya is more of a place for theory and not actual halachic rulings.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of "am i Jewish"? This question is about reform conversion, while the duplicate is about being Jewish if the ancestors left Judaism. Am i missing something?